# Torque -rod on a wall

Tags: torque

I saw this problem and ive been thinking about it... A rod is embedded on a wall, so that its angle with the wall is 90° it has mass m, and there is a force F (downwards) on its end.
Ignoring gravity, what is the force of the wall on the rod so that the rod has no movement.
So at first glance i thought it had to be oposite to F but then that creates a couple. Then i tried to simplify it, for no movement net force must be 0;
Net torque must be 0 on all points but the pivot is on the wall and so that screws with the torque formula, am i over complicating this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

Force due to the wall will be $F_1$ in upwards direction due to force balance.To know the real picture see the figure (Sorry for the bad drawing), when a rod is inserted into a wall there is a distribution of forces acting on it. 
Now if you use force balance you will get:
$$F_3 - F_2 + F_1 = 0 $$
This $F_2 - F_3$ is the total force that wall applies on the rod and if $F_1$ is downwards then $F_2$ will be greater than $F_3$ so that all three balance each other.

[image]
Each distribution can be represented by force on a appropriate point of application such that total moment of distributed force is equal to the moment of force applied at that equivalent point of application.
In this figure I have shown the equivalent points of application of each force individually. If you know the distances of point of applications then you can use moment balance about any point and you will get a consistent picture.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is necessary to include the depth that the rod is inserted into the wall or the thickness of the glue attaching it to the wall. There would be a greater force on the end, further from the center, and a force in the opposite direction, a little closer to the center.